# I haven't been able to install Radon Software for Linux on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, dependencies, 22.04, radeon

I recently build my first Desktop PC and I installed both Windows 11 (for work stuff) Ubuntu 22.04 (for everything else since I really don't like windows) and I've been using it for a while but every time I've tried to install Radon Software for Linux I go to AMD Radeon website, select my GPU (A RX6500XT) and download the latest "amdgpu-install....deb", I install it and then run amdgpu-install and every time I get this error:

```
rocm-llvm : Depends: python but not installable
            Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but not installable or
                     libstdc++-7-dev but not installable
            Depends: libgcc-5-dev but is not installable or
                     libgcc-7-dev but not installable
            Recommends: gcc-multilib but it won't install
            Recommends: g++-multilib but it won't install
E: Problems could not be corrected, you have held broken packages.
```

I know that on Windows the radeon software gives you several option like enable FSR, Antilag, Chill, etc. But from what I know, all this works difenrent on linux and makes me wonder if it's even necesary to install Radon Software for Linux or I'm fine with the kernel drivers.

Is it recomended to install Radon Software for Linux? and in this case, How can I install it?

Latest installer I've tried: amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb

Downloaded from: https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-22-20

Comment: Apparently, you've installed something old and unsupported, because there is no `libgcc-5-dev` for 22.04, but there are `libgcc-10/11/12`. Here is the right page for [Ubutnu 22.04 Radeon Software](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-22-20). Remove whatever is installed, so it does not conflict with new stuff.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt purge amdgpu-install && sudo apt autoremove`, and tried with the one from the link you provided but still got the same error

Comment: You don't need any drivers.